# How do you obtain evidence for GDPR violations?

Tags: gdpr, european-union, investigation

What happens when say company EvilkorP sends untrue information and/or information that it is not entitled to share to company Y, and EvilkorP asks company Y to mention some fact about the victim (you) that is only known by EvilkorP?

What do investigators do?

Comment: I would be looking for evidence that EvilkorP has defamed me, and also breached GDPR rules by sending defamatory information to Y, where Y is Packetvideo.

Comment: It would seem that the GDPR is more honored in the breach. eg. https://derspreebogen.home.blog/should-you-trust-german-car-makers-with-your-private-data/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the law or legal process, or the legal professions.

Comment: Isn't obtaining evidence 90% of the judicial process?

Comment: No, it's a scientific process heavily influenced by sociological and legal (and sometimes political) factors, but not part of the legal process itself. Rules of evidence in a courtroom, whether a particular means of gaining evidence is legal, or similar questions are about the law; asking how to get the evidence in the first place is not.

Comment: Please, remove the rant part of the question.  There is nothing "evil" about refusing to comply with GDPR outside of the European jurisdiction.  This site's purpose is not politicking.  In fact, in certain jurisdiction (the US comes to mind), demanding that a company does comply with GDPR would likely (not necessarily, but *likely*) be seen as unethical.

Answer (score 2):

You can submit [GDPR requests](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/individual-rights/right-of-access/) to both companies asking them what information they have about you and who they have disclosed it to. They are legally required to provide this information apart from [certain exemptions](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/exemptions/). If they fail to do so then they are in breach of the GDPR.

Comment: What if the companies involved don't answer truthfully? Yes, it's obviously illegal to do so, but how would you prove it?

Comment: I think the only way to have a hope of finding out is to make an SAR for every marketing contact, and all their up and downstream data contacts.  Any lies that are exposed outside the company should be detectable.  A software tool is probably required to do this efficiently.